# Python: increment index range by 1

Tags: python, loops, indexing, increment

I have this code:

```
f = open('story.txt', 'r')
story = f.read()


a = 0
b = 2
active_words = story[a:b]
```

I'm trying to make it so later on in the program I can increase the range of this index by (+1), so that instead of taking one word out of the story as active_words, it takes 2,3,4... etc. Ideally this would be able to happen inside part of a while loop.

My apologies for my lack of formatting, this is my first post.

I'm also just starting to learn python and so there's probably a dead easy solution I've overlooked... I've tried trying to define a function like extend(active_words), but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't clear. Are you trying to generate successive slices which look like `story[0:2], story[0:3], story[0:4] ...` or `story[0:2], story[2:5], story[5:9] ...`? If the former, then it is dead easy: `for i in range(2,len(story)): active_words = story[:i]`  (no need to specify the `0`)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the reply! Sorry about it not being clear... Ideally i'd be able to control both of the parameters, and be able to either extend the length of the slice (from 0:1 to 0:2, for example), but also start a new slice (from 1:3 to 3:4, for example). Is that more clear?

Comment: Clarifications go in to your question. Use the [edit] button below your post to do so. What is wrong with changing the values of `a` and `b`? From your set-up it seems all that's necessary (although the jump from characters to *words* is not addressed in your very short sample code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic nested for-loop seems to be what you are looking for:

```
n = len(story)
for k in range(2,n+1):
    for j in range(n-k+1):
        active_words = story[j:j+k]
```

The outer loop controls the length of the slice and the inner loop actually generates the slices.

Note that these are just string slices, which will contain fragments of words. You might want something like `story = story.split()` prior to the loop.

Comment: I just tried this out in the context of my program and it splits "story" into a list of the words in the story. It's likely that I'm using it wrong because I'm still not super confident in Python. I'm not sure how posting works in stack overflow, but is it possible that I post all of the code in my program to show the context of my question? Is that proper "stack-etiquette"? Ahahah thank you for your help regardless, though!

Comment: You could perhaps ask another question if you want. Mutating questions to ask follow up questions isn't considered good etiquette since it makes your question a moving target. On the other hand, if what you add clarifies the original question then edit it in. The code I gave above works for either strings or lists. If `story` is a list of words then it will generate all slices from that list of length at least 2. The loop itself splits nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and describe to you how my program works..

It's a program that looks for anagrams in (story). I have a list of names in ```resources``` that have been turned into anagrams and hidden in ```story```. How it operates is I split both the names in the list and the ```active_words``` into a set of letters and search all the names for an intersection. This then compiles a list of names called ```matches``` that consists of names that match the letters of ```active_words```. Now I need to increase ```active_words``` (and repeat the intersection test), which is the issue.

Comment: That would require a follow up question, and one that is clearer than that comment. You asked about how to loop through the slices in a string and that question has been answered. It would stretch the question beyond recognition to start talking about a program which involves multiple lists and strings, some of which are anagrams of each other.

Comment: Alright, thank you. and my apologies for the unclear question!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to split a sentence into words?
if so, try instead using:

```
story = f.read()
words = story.split()
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Comment: Thank you but I've managed to do that in my program already. Thanks a bunch regardless!